# Getting Travelling time including traffic

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

Get realtime expected time including traffic. I want to get this time **29 Min**.

I tried https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=28.520033,48.412325&destinations=28.545754,%2048.387446&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyD-HnbCNCezdpWRAHWqjaavkAOdbEn-m8E&departure_time=1457946607160 but it's returning without traffic.

[image]

Comment: That is very little information you're sharing. You are not listing your request, only the response. So what did you try? I assume you read the api docs at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#traffic-model?

Comment: I am calling this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=28.520033,48.412325&destinations=28.545754,%2048.387446&mode=driving

Comment: But the duration is always 6 Min

Comment: I have added &departure_time=1457946607160 but still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my link in the comment above (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters):

traffic_model (defaults to best_guess) — Specifies the assumptions to use when calculating time in traffic. This setting affects the value returned in the duration_in_traffic field in the response, which contains the predicted time in traffic based on historical averages. The traffic_model parameter may only be specified for requests *where the travel mode is driving, and where the request includes a departure_time, and only if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID*

As far as I can see your request includes neither departure_time nor any api key. Go register yourself a api key and follow the documentation, and you should probably be fine.

Comment: I tried that. UPDATED my URL. But still result is not same.

Comment: I clearly see a `duration_in_traffic` field in your response above now. What is the issue..?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider not publishing your own private api key for the world to see as well. Sure, it's a free service, but there may be a quota etc. It did simplify helping you though, so I'm not complaining. :-)

Comment: Actually I have noticed one thing in google map itself If you are putting Leave now then time taken is different with departure Time - current time. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't really understand. Is this a completely different question? Was your original problem solved? If so, please accept answer and if needed raise a new question.

Comment: Yes looks like I am getting original value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106250/discussion-between-bumba-and-jhh).